# getExtras() returns null on back navigation

Tags: java, android

So, I am starting `MainActivity.java` is having following code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("testString", "TestString");
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

And My `ScondActivity.java` is having following code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("testString");
    Log.v(SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName(), s);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("testString", "TestString");
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

And my `ThirdActivity.java` having following code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("testString");
    Log.v(ThirdActivity.class.getSimpleName(), s);
}
```

While I run this app, everything works fine. But when I come back from `ThirdActivity.java` to `SecondActivity.java` I am getting `NullPointerException` on `String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("testString");`.

How can I overcome this issue?

Any possible help can be highly appreciable.

Comment: save that value in the sharedPref and after that use it

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because the data passed from one activity to another activity using `Intent` is temporary and is destroyed when you switch to another activity.
As you switch from SecondActivity to ThirdActivity, the extras from FirstActivity are destroyed. An alternative to this problem is that you can store these extras in Shared Preferences. Using shared preferences will save you data to local storage and it will be available on every activity.
A guide to shared preferences can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Actually I don't want to keep the data in any storage. That's I tried get it from intent itself. Anyway thanks for your clarification on `Extras`. Nice, added +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onSaveInstanceState() from the activity's lifecycle methods to tackle this problem. Please have a look at the following URL: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

A paragraph from the link that I have provided:

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed. However, if the system destroys the activity due to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed. The saved data that the system uses to restore the previous state is called the "instance state" and is a collection of key-value pairs stored in a Bundle object.
>
> ...
>
> To save additional data about the activity state, you must override the onSaveInstanceState() callback method. The system calls this method when the user is leaving your activity and passes it the Bundle object that will be saved in the event that your activity is destroyed unexpectedly. If the system must recreate the activity instance later, it passes the same Bundle object to both the onRestoreInstanceState() and onCreate() methods.

So instead of creating your own shared preferences, you can use the onSaveInstanceState() and the Bundle that's passed as parameter from the onCreate(or the onRestoreInstanceState).

Answer (score 0):

Change your onCreate Method below code in both Second and Tird Activity

```
  String s = "";
  if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
   {
        s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("testString");
        Log.v(SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName(), s);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Second Activity declare your `s` as instance variable.

```
String s;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("testString");
    Log.v(SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName(), s);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("testString", "TestString");
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

The code is read from Top to down and the value assigned to a variable inside that certain method will only last until the pointer reaches the last brace of that method onCreate. The click listener can happen at any moment depending on the user of course, by that time the value is no longer living so you get a null value.

Assigning the value to the Instance variable will last until that instance lifespan. Therefore any usage from that variable will guarantee the recovery of that certain value being assigned a while ago.

Take consider also that the OS might kill the activity (Dequeued from the Activity Stack) when there no enough memory while your activity is in the background. If that happens it is much safer to use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`.